# require_once (массив файлов) в цикле

Tags: php

Есть цикл:

```
foreach(array('1.php', '2.php', '3.php') as $require_file)
{
    require_once($require_file);
}
```

Вопрос: Есть ли вероятность увеличения нагрузки на сервер и уменьшение производительности системы в целом, или наоборот?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Есть ли вероятность увеличения нагрузки на сервер

Простите, в сравнении с чем ?

Подключать 5 файлов отдельно или 5 файлов в цикле ? Нет, разницы не будет. Посмотрите также в сторону автолоадера.

Comment: в стравнении подключения 5 файлов по отдельности!

Comment: Плюс надо учесть то, что require_once выдает фатал эрор при отсутствии  файла, так что далее цикл может быть прерван

Comment: @ROOT отсутствие файла уже учтено, die();

Comment: >> в стравнении подключения 5 файлов по отдельности!

Нет, разницы никакой не будет в производительности.

Comment: ответом удовлетворен, благодарствую)

Answer (score 2):

В цикле нагрузка, конечно, будет выше (для любителей экономить на спичках - на одну спичку). А вот если вы хотите действительно снизить нагрузку, используйте require вместо require_once или напишите свою функцию для проверки подключенных файлов.